# Mapping array of string inside array of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have this json object that I'm trying to map:

```
{
    totalresults: 1,
    results: [
              {
                  sources: [
                            "The Blog",
                            "The website",
                            ],
                  description: "Some description."",
                  subjects: [
                             "Education"
                             ],
                  imageurl: "image.jpg",
                  authorid: 44303,
                  istail: false,
                  tailcount: 0,
                  displayname: "Name of me"
              }
          ]
}
```

**I've created a SearchPerPage object:**

```
@interface RestSearchPerPage : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *totalResults;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *results;
@end
```

**I've created a SearchResults object:**

```
@interface SearchResults : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sources;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *subjects;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *content;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imageUrl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *authorId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *displayName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *isTail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *tailCount;
@end
```

I'm mapping the objects just fine, but when I'm trying to map the `NSArray *sources` and `NSArray *subjects` I always get `NULL`.

**This is my last mapping attempt on sources:**

```
RKObjectMapping *searchResultsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SearchResults class]];
[searchResultsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"sources" : @"sources",
                                                            @"subjects" : @"subjects",
                                                            @"description" : @"content",
                                                            @"imageurl" : @"imageUrl",
                                                            @"authorid" : @"authorId",
                                                            @"displayname" : @"displayName",
                                                            @"istail" : @"isTail",
                                                            @"tailcount" : @"tailCount" }];

RKObjectMapping *searchPerPageMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SearchPerPage class]];
[searchPerPageMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"totalresults" : @"totalResults" }];
[searchPerPageMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"results" toKeyPath:@"results" withMapping:searchResultsMapping]];


[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:searchPerPageMapping
                                                                                                    method:self.method
                                                                                               pathPattern:kGetSearchPerPage
                                                                                                   keyPath:nil
                                                                                               statusCodes:self.statusCode]];
```

Please help me because I'm lost, just don't know what to do next - have no answer to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that I didn't mapped the array of 'results' like that:

```
[searchPerPageMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"results" toKeyPath:@"results" withMapping:searchResultsMapping]];
```

I've edited my question and fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Are you making sure that you're initializing the arrays e.g.

```
NSArray *subjects = [NSArray array];
```

It's very common to forget this :)

Comment: cool, I like how you just downvote my answer without explanation when I'm just trying to give suggestions.